# Dragstart not triggered

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I dynamically create an image which I apend to my DOM structure :

```
var thumb = document.createElement("img");
            thumb.draggable = "true";
            thumb.alt = label;
            thumb.id = "dhmvseries_" + label;
            thumb.setAttribute("dhmvseriesuuid",label);
            thumb.ondragstart = thumbDragStart;
            thumb.ondragend = thumbDragEnd;
            thumb.onmouseover = displayThumbInfo;
            thumb.onmouseout = hideThumbInfo;
```

I call 4 methods on this image. The methods `onmouseover` and `mouseout` are "fired" normally but the two drag functions do absolutely nothing. What could be blocking them? Help me please!

Comment: The [`draggable` reflected property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/dnd.html#dom-draggable) is a boolean, so you don't want the quotes in `thumb.draggable = "true"`. But that's not likely to be the problem, as the string `"true"` is truthy anyway, and `img` elements are draggable by default.

Answer (score 0):

The content was opened in JQuery UI dialog which had an modal option se to true. This was causing drag&drop problems. Fixed